# gradle config of library project

Tags: android, gradle

Am building an android library which itself depended on other library, my question where do I put all the repo and configuration ? module gradle file or the project root gradle file. The reason why am asking the question is am getting too many custom attribute and theme not found exception while integrating the with other app. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Theme , dependency , permissions should be in android library project. So that while integrating with any other project it should be working without any compile/runtime errors. Which ever the dependency this library uses should be resolved within the library context itself. For example bundle.gradle in library project

Comment: Am using calligraphy but when I attached to main project am getting fontPath not found

Comment: In library module.gradle put compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:x.x.x'  and create class extending Application in library itself and initiate in onCreate using CalligraphyConfig.initDefault . So that all the necessary configurations are done in library alone. So that linking into any other project is possible.

Comment: Library module already have that config

Comment: I figured out the issue, for local aar all the dependency should be resolved locally , ie keep all the depended aar within the main library or publish it

Comment: That is what I have mentioned in first comment  !

Comment: Thanks, one more thing.. I have two local sub library which I have added into the my library as compile('name:file', 'ext=aar') compile('name:file', 'ext=jar') but both of them throwing class not found exception. Can you pleas help me